# How to remove 1px space between ListViewItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

In ListView between ListViewItems have 1px space and it causing me to miss click between them frequently. This only happens if ListViewItem in ListViewGroup.

I recorded video to show it: https://jaex.getsharex.com/2022/06/pBBk1aXmD6.mp4

In video I can click between two items which makes ListViewItem unselected. This problem not happens if I don't use ListViewGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this workaround now:

```
    private void lvMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lvMain.SelectedItems.Count == 0 && (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left || e.Button == MouseButtons.Right))
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = lvMain.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);

            if (lvi == null)
            {
                // Workaround for 1px space between items
                lvi = lvMain.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y - 1);
            }

            if (lvi != null)
            {
                lvi.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

If clicked to empty space between two items then checking one pixel top of this position and if item exist in this position then selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such property to set. Maybe you could draw the `ListViewGroup` yourself. Or try to solve it without group, which is apparently inceonvenient for you though.

Or store the selection in a variable, create a background worker/click event to check button clicks on ListViewGroup, and if nothing is selected set it back to the previous.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property to assign value like that. But, you can customize your list item by drawing each `ListViewItem` in `DrawItem` event. you need to assign `OwenerDraw` event first for that.

**Check out the example given in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**